# High performance Charts for live data on web browser

Tags: javascript, charts, real-time

I'm trying to make a [Arduino Science Journal](https://www.arduino.cc/education/science-journal) App, but for web. My problem is the performance with the charts, most of the charts say "High performance, over 100k points", but statics points and live data are different. I tried a few charts, it turn very laggy with 200ms of data.

I need recommendations for charts, I also want that my project be Open Source, so I'm trying to avoid charts with private licence.